# Changing the IP address of our SharePoint Servers. What are the Risks

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are going to change the IP address of our SharePoint Servers can any one point out the RISK and IMPACT

Answer (score 5):

Changing IP address usually not a big deal, You need to make sure...

- All DNS record updated and point to the new IP
- if you use IP in the AAM then you have to update it.
- if anything on IIS bindings you need to update.